Prove that $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|\leq7$

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial function and $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Prove, if $|P(x)|$$\leq1$ for all $x$ with $|x|\leq1$, then $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|\leq7$.

This problem is from the IMO 1996 Short List. I have attempted to solve the question as follows:
Without the loss of generality $a,b\geq0$.
Case 1: If $c,d\geq0$, then 
$|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|=a+b+c+d=P(1)\leq1<7$.
Case 2: If $d\leq0$ and $c\geq0$ then 
$|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|=a+b+c-d=(a+b+c+d)-2d=P(1)-2P(0)\leq1+2=3<7.$
I am unable to continue for I am unable to prove the inequality for Case 3 ($d\geq0$, $c<0$) and Case 4 ($d<0$, $c<0$) respectively. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What makes $c<0$ tough(er) is the fact that this includes a sharp-bound example, $4x^3-3x$.

What about $P(1)$, $P(-1)$ and $\frac{P(x)}{x^2}$ for $x=\pm \frac{1}{2}$?

This question is similar to: Maximum value of the sum of absolute values of cubic polynomial coefficients $a,b,c,d$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an ...

(cont.) Approach0 search. In particular, this answer there not only provides a relatively simple and straight-forward proof, but also gives an example showing where $7$ is the sum of those values. Note there are also other closely related questions here, e.g., How use Lagrange interpolation prove this inequality and Problem require Lagrange interpolation. In ...

(cont.) addition, there are the AoPS threads Cubic polynomial with absolute value inequality and Polynomial in equation problem, and also the fairly closely related HOMC (Vietnam). Finally, welcome to Math SE.

Hint: Try expressing $a+b-c+d$ and $a+b-c-d$ using $P(1)$, $P(1/2)$, $P(-1/2)$ and $P(-1)$.
